# Cannot read my attributes in database

Tags: php, html

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
    require('db_connect.php');
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $food_name = $_POST['food_name'];
    $restaurant_name = $_POST['restaurant_name'];
    $food_type = $_POST['food_type'];
    $food_price = $_POST['food_price'];
    $food_description = $_POST['food_description'];
    $uploadfile;

    $dest_folder = "picture/";
    $arr = array();
    $count = 0;

    if(!file_exists($dest_folder)){
        mkdir($dest_folder);
    }

    foreach($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key=> $error){
        if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
            $uploadfile = $dest_folder.$name;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$uploadfile);
            $arr[$count] = $uploadfile;
            $count++;
        }
    }

    $s2 = implode(',',$arr);

    $sql = "insert into foodmenu 
            (food_name,restaurant_name,food_type,food_price,food_description,food_img) 
            values 
            ('$food_name','$restaurant_name','$food_type','$food_price','$food_description','$s2',now())";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    if($result){
        echo"<script>alert('Success')</script>";
        echo"<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";
    } else {
        echo"<script>alert('Failure')</script>";
        echo"<script>history.back();</script>";
    }    
?>
```

May I know what is the error?
Because it cannot read my $food_name till $food_description.....and foreach($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as &key=>$error).....
Can provide any solution for it?

```
<form action="add_action.php" method="post" name="send" onSubmit="return Check()"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Food Name ：
    
    
    
    

    
    Food Description ：
    
    
    
    

    
    Food Price ：
    
$  
    
    

    
    Food Type ：
    
    
    ---
    appertizers
    main courses
    desserts
    
    
    

    
    Restaurant Name ：
    
    
    
    

    
    Images ：

```
<input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="inputButton" id="btnSubmit" value=" ADD " align="middle">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also add the form that posts the data to your script?

Answer (score 0):

There's lot of things that may happen wrong in your form.

First one is, It is possible that your form input name and your `&_POST['xyz']` names are not matching.

Second one is, Please never forget to wrap your post values in htmlspecialchars like `$food_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['food_name']);`

Neither your values are thrown for injection threats.
So after two above mentioned modifications, if you still face the problem, please attach your form html. 
i'm excluding your db_connect.php. Please edit the details as your own.
sql code::'

```
 <?php
 define("DB_DSN","mysql:hostname=localhost;dbname=tumy");
    define("DB_USR","root");
    define("DB_PASS","");
    $conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USR,DB_PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    $food_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['food_name']);
    $restaurant_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['restaurant_name']);
    $food_type = htmlspecialchars($_POST['food_type']);
    $food_price = htmlspecialchars($_POST['food_price']);
    $food_description = htmlspecialchars($_POST['food_description']);
    $date = now();//create a column in your database named "date(or as wish)
    $dest_folder = "picture/";

    $arr = array();
    $count = 0;

    if(!file_exists($dest_folder)){
        mkdir($dest_folder);
    }

    foreach($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key=> $error){
        if($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK){
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
            $uploadfile = $dest_folder.$name;
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$uploadfile);
            $arr[$count] = $uploadfile;
            $count++;
        }
    }

    $s2 = implode(',',$arr);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO foodmenu 
            (food_name,restaurant_name,food_type,food_price,food_description,food_img,date) 
            VALUES
            ('$food_name','$restaurant_name','$food_type','$food_price','$food_description','$s2','$date')";

    $st = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if($st->execute()){
        echo"<script>alert('Success')</script>";
        echo"<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";
    } else {
        echo"<script>alert('Failure')</script>";
        echo"<script>history.back();</script>";
    }    
    $conn = null;
?>`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply..... I tried both solutions that u recommend but it still can't read my attributes which already set in the database...

Comment: It said "invalid argument supplied for foreach()"....... Is that the image that I uploaded must be from the file name "pictures" that mention in $_FILES["pictures"] ??

Comment: bro, who told you to set input type="uploadFile"???..... this is not a valid file type for html.  put input  type="file"

Comment: Also your sql query needs two more columns to store image address and    current time.

Comment: what is means by needs 2 more columns? means put this code twice? : <input type="file" name="pictures" />

Comment: Hey @Lim, i've updated my answer, converting your sql code into PDO. and i think this would be the solution for your problem. Also in your  form action, why are you returning a function???.....use it as ' onSubmit = "check()" '

Comment: Hi, is that need <?php for the opening? If not it shows "success" pop up message, but the data key in didn't insert into foodmenu table. Why?

Comment: If change at the top of code, it cannot read PDO code with message "fatal error: uncaught exception 'PDO Exception' with message 'invalid data source name'".....define("DB_HOST","localhost");
    define("DB_NAME","tumy");
    define("DB_USER","root");
    define("DB_PASSWORD","");
    $conn = new PDO(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

Comment: yes it needs <?php at the beginning. but it doesn't affect your result.  By the way, where did i mention DB_HOST???. DSN contains server variables.  Use as i mentioned.....now i have re-edited my answer according to your server. By the way, dbname is the name of database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="listbox">
<div class="menu">
<br><br>      
<form action="add_action.php" method="post" name="send" onSubmit="return Check()"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

<tr>
<td width="180" align="right">Food Name ：</td>
<td width="150">
<input name="food_name" type="text" class="food_namelist" style="width:300px;">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" align="right">Food Description ：</td>
<td width="222">
<textarea name="food_description" class="food_namelist" rows="3" style="height:100px; width:500px;"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="100" align="right">Food Price ：</td>
<td width="222">
```

$

```
<tr>
<td width="100" align="right">Food Type ：</td>
<td width="222">
<select name="food_type">
<option value="" selected>---</option>
<option value="appertizers">appertizers</option>
<option value="main courses">main courses</option>
<option value="desserts">desserts</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td width="180" align="right">Restaurant Name ：</td>
<td width="222">
<input name="restaurant_name" type="text" class="food_namelist" style="width:300px;">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right">Images ：</td>
<td style=" ">
<input type="uploadfile" name="pictures[]" />
</td>
</tr>

</table>
<input name="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="inputButton" id="btnSubmit" value=" ADD " align="middle">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```